# Show table records based on user condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a web application backed by SQL Server database. It has a report, that combines students of selected semesters and a specific way. the following image show the interface for selecting semester and number of students.

[image]

The user selects the semesters and enters numbers of students.
To be clear, suppose a user enters `3` students and selects `1th` and `2th` semesters. The system should return all students which are enrolled in `1th` and `2th` semester as following:

```
------------------------
Id  StudentName Semester
------------------------
1       A          First
4       D          First
7       G          First
2       B          Second
3       C          Second
5       E          Second
9       I          First
10      J          First
12      L          First
6       F          Second
8       H          Second
11      K          Second
```

The dataset is as follow:

**Student Table**

```
-----------------
Id  StudentName
-----------------
1       A
2       B
3       C
4       D
5       E
6       F
7       G
8       H
9       I
10      J
11      K
12      L
```

**Semester Table**

```
-----------------
Id  Semester
-----------------
1       First
2       Second
3       Third
```

**Enrollment Table**

```
----------------------------
Id  StudentID   SemesterID
----------------------------
1      1            1
2      2            2
3      3            2
4      4            1
5      5            2
6      6            2
7      7            1
8      8            2
9      9            1
10     10           1
11     11           2
12     12           1
```

Any idea on how to show the records of the above table as mentioned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to approach this is to start with the `Enrollment` table. Using the [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) ranking function, you can assign row numbers in groups of `SemesterID`:

```
SELECT
  *,
  RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SemesterID ORDER BY Id ASC)
FROM
  dbo.Enrollment
;
```

For your example you will get output like this:

```
Id  StudentID  SemesterID  RN
--  ---------  ----------  --
1   1          1           1
2   2          2           1
3   3          2           2
4   4          1           2
5   5          2           3
6   6          2           4
7   7          1           3
8   8          2           5
9   9          1           4
10  10         1           5
11  11         2           6
12  12         1           6
```

Now subtract one from `RN` and then divide the result by the required number of students. If the number of students is 3, then you will find that the aforementioned calculation turns a sequence of

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...
```

into

```
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, ...
```

That is to say, you will get a sequence consisting of groups of repeating numbers, three per group (because we divided by three). You can use that result as the primary sorting criterion.

Choose `SemesterID` as your second criterion and `Id` or `StudentID` as the third, so now the query will look like this:

```
SELECT
  *,
  GroupID = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SemesterID ORDER BY Id ASC) - 1) / 3
FROM
  dbo.Enrollment
ORDER BY
  GroupID ASC,
  SemesterID ASC,
  Id ASC
;
```

And this will be its output based on the sample provided:

```
Id  StudentID  SemesterID  GroupID
--  ---------  ----------  -------
1   1          1           0
4   4          1           0
7   7          1           0
2   2          2           0
3   3          2           0
5   5          2           0
9   9          1           1
10  10         1           1
12  12         1           1
6   6          2           1
8   8          2           1
11  11         2           1
```

You can see that the order of rows already matches the expected output, you just need to replace `StudentID` and `SemesterID` with their descriptions and get rid of the `GroupID`. Declare the above query as either a derived table or a CTE and then join tables `Student` and `Semester` to it. For my answer I chose the CTE option, and this is what I got:

```
WITH
  RankedData AS
  (
    SELECT
      *,
      GroupID = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SemesterID ORDER BY Id ASC) - 1) / 3
    FROM
      dbo.Enrollment
  )
SELECT
  rd.Id,
  st.StudentName,
  sm.Semester
FROM
  RankedData AS rd
  INNER JOIN dbo.Student AS st ON rd.StudentID = st.Id
  INNER JOIN dbo.Semester AS sm ON rd.SemesterID = sm.Id
ORDER BY
  rd.GroupID ASC,
  rd.SemesterID ASC,
  rd.Id ASC
;
```

Output:

```
Id  StudentName Semester
--  ----------- --------
1   A           First
4   D           First
7   G           First
2   B           Second
3   C           Second
5   E           Second
9   I           First
10  J           First
12  L           First
6   F           Second
8   H           Second
11  K           Second
```

As you can see, the query we have so far works perfectly for the provided example: the results now match your expected output precisely. But the query is not finished yet: the filter on semester is missing.

Assuming that semesters will be provided as a comma-separated list of names/descriptions, what you can do is turn that list into a row set, with one name/description per row. You can then match that row set against the `Semester` table to include just the selected semesters. For the purpose of this answer I am assuming that you are using SQL Server 2016 or later version, so that the built-in [`SPLIT_STRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) function can be used to help implement the semester filter:

```
WITH
  RankedData AS
  (
    SELECT
      *,
      GroupID = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SemesterID ORDER BY Id ASC) - 1) / 3
    FROM
      dbo.Enrollment
  )
SELECT
  rd.Id,
  st.StudentName,
  sm.Semester
FROM
  RankedData AS rd
  INNER JOIN dbo.Student  AS st ON rd.StudentID  = st.Id
  INNER JOIN dbo.Semester AS sm ON rd.SemesterID = sm.Id
WHERE
  sm.Semester IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT('First,Second', ','))
ORDER BY
  rd.GroupID ASC,
  rd.SemesterID ASC,
  rd.Id ASC
;
```

In an earlier version of SQL Server you will have to provide your own method of turning a string list into a row set of substrings. Thankfully, solutions abound on the Internet, including the many questions and answers dedicated to this problem both here and on Stack Overflow. [Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand) discusses various methods in his blog article, [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings), which can be a good starting point.

As for our query, there remains one last step to take: parametrisation. Both the number of students and the list of selected semesters were hard-coded in the above queries. The final solution will need to use parameter references instead of the hard-coded values, something like this:

```
WITH
  RankedData AS
  (
    SELECT
      *,
      GroupID = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SemesterID ORDER BY Id ASC) - 1) / @NumberOfStudents
    FROM
      dbo.Enrollment
  )
SELECT
  rd.Id,
  st.StudentName,
  sm.Semester
FROM
  RankedData AS rd
  INNER JOIN dbo.Student  AS st ON rd.StudentID  = st.Id
  INNER JOIN dbo.Semester AS sm ON rd.SemesterID = sm.Id
WHERE
  sm.Semester IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@SemesterList, ','))
ORDER BY
  rd.GroupID ASC,
  rd.SemesterID ASC,
  rd.Id ASC
;
```

A [live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c9d08f79b49d58bc03d5eeefead5ccca) of this solution is available at [image: dbfiddle logo]db<>fiddle.uk.

---

<sub>Disclosure: this answer borrows partly from the now deleted answer by [Josh Darnell](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/6141/josh-darnell).</sub>